# Searchable SearchView setSuggestionsAdapter() in android studio

Tags: android, searchview, searchable

I'm working on an app. It requires a searchview. im facing a problem while working with cursor adaptor. i simply want a string array or xml string array to displayed in suggestion adaptor. when i click on search button it show suggestion and on suggestion click it do given work.
i need codes that will help me sort out this problem. I'm not a professional programmer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve Using **SearchAutoComplete** view,try something below like this

```
      @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

           getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_menu, menu);
           searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)

           searchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();
           searchAutoComplete = (SearchView.SearchAutoComplete) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);

           SearchManager searchManager =
                            (SearchManager) getSystemService(this.SEARCH_SERVICE);
                    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

           ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.suggetion, jsonArrayList);

                    // jsonarraylist is static string array

           searchAutoComplete.setAdapter(adapter);

           searchAutoComplete.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                          // Your code for onitemclick
           }
        }
```

activity_main_menu.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_search"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
            android:title="@string/search"
            app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
            app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"/>
    </menu>
```

suggetion.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/dropDownItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargePopupMenu"/>
```

I hope this may help you,All the best.

Comment: Thanks a lot brother everything is working fine. Just one more thing hoiw i can implement layour.suggestion. :)

Comment: sorry,forget to mention... Edited :)

Comment: Thanku so much :). What if i want it to implement to fragment(In Navigation Bar Layout)

Comment: Sorry for the disturbance. its working fine in fragment but one problem it only displays item after 2 3 alphabets matches the first alphabets. otherwise it does not displays the item.

Comment: for that you required:   searchAutoComplete.setThreshold (0);